# Unable to update profile data into database after user login using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Once user login into the website it will fetch the details of the login users based on profile ids.If i try to update the details of the user unable to update as well as not getting any issues.

Controller:

```
function index()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in'))
    {
        $data['admin_details'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');
        $data['country'] = $this->signup_model->getcountry();       
        $data['states'] = $this->profile_model->getstates();
        $data['records']= $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')['profile_id']);
        $data['mainpage']='profile';
        //echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar',$data);
    }
    else
    {           
        $this->load->view('welcome');
    }
}

function updateprofile()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('profile_name','Profile Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('designation','Designation','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address_1','Address','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address_2','Address','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
    {   
    $data['records']= $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')['profile_id']);      
    $data['mainpage']='profile';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar',$data);
    }
    else    
        {       
            $result = $this->profile_model->update($this->input->post('profile_id'));       
            if(is_array($result))
            {       
                $data['errors']=$result;
                $data['records']= $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')['profile_id']);                 
                $data['mainpage']='profile';
                $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
                $this->load->view('templates/sidebar',$data);
            }                              
                else                    
                $this->flash->success('<h2>Successfully Updated the record.<h2>');                      
                redirect('profile');                    
        }               

}
```

Model:

```
function getprofiledata($id)
{
    $this->db->select('profile_details.*,C.country_name,S.state_name,D.city_name');     
    $this->db->from('profile_details');
    $this->db->join('countries AS C','C.country_id=profile_details.country_id','INNER');
    $this->db->join('states AS S','S.state_id=profile_details.state_id','INNER');
    $this->db->join('cities AS D','D.city_id=profile_details.city_id','INNER');
    $this->db->where(array('profile_details.profile_id'=>$id));     
    $q=$this->db->get();        
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    return $q->result();
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}

function update($id)
{
    $data=array(
    'first_name' =>$this->input->post('first_name'),
    'profile_name' =>$this->input->post('profile_name'),
    'designation' =>$this->input->post('designation'),
    'address_1' =>$this->input->post('address_1'),
    'address_2' =>$this->input->post('address_2')       
    );
    $this->db->where(array('profile_id'=>$id));
    $this->db->update('profile_details', $data);
    return true;        
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">
<div id="legend">
    <legend class="">Profile Information</legend>
</div>   
<?php if(isset($records) && is_array($records) && count($records)>0): ?>
            <?php foreach($records as $r):?>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>profile/updateprofile" role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="location" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <?php
        echo form_hidden('profile_id',$r->profile_id);
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="name">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" nae="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Enter name" value="<?php echo $r->first_name;?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="profilename">Profile Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profile_name" id="profile_name" placeholder="Enter Profile name" value="<?php echo $r->profile_name;?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="designation">Designation:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="designation" id="designation" placeholder="Enter Designation" value="<?php echo $r->designation;?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="address_1">Address 1:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_1" name="address_1" placeholder="Enter Address Details" value="<?php echo $r->address_1;?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="address_2">Address 2:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_2" name="address_2"  placeholder="Enter Address Details" value="<?php echo $r->address_2;?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <?php endforeach;endif;?>
    </div>
```

Once user login into the website unable to update the data into database.Once submitting the form redirecting to same page not getting any issue as well.

Comment: any help it will be really helpful for me thanks in advance

Comment: Any one  please can help me this

Comment: Any one please help me out with this problem

Answer (score 0):

**Dear user7047368,**

Maybe problems at your model code.

```
function update($id)
{
    $data=array(
    'first_name' =>$this->input->post('first_name'),
    'profile_name' =>$this->input->post('profile_name'),
    'designation' =>$this->input->post('designation'),
    'address_1' =>$this->input->post('address_1'),
    'address_2' =>$this->input->post('address_2'),

    );
    $this->db->where(array('profile_id'=>$id));
    $this->db->update('profile_details', $data);
    return true;        
}
```

MUST BE (you type an extra comma in `$data(array)`)

```
function update($id)
{
    $data=array(
    'first_name' =>$this->input->post('first_name'),
    'profile_name' =>$this->input->post('profile_name'),
    'designation' =>$this->input->post('designation'),
    'address_1' =>$this->input->post('address_1'),
    'address_2' =>$this->input->post('address_2')
    );
    $this->db->where(array('profile_id'=>$id));
    $this->db->update('profile_details', $data);
    return true;        
}
```

If you not sure your query is true or false, you can put this line `var_dump($this->db->last_query());` into this function after `$this->db->update('profile_details', $data);`; then copy it and paste into **Query Form** in your phpmyadmin.

Hope this help.

Comment: Tried this as well but not getting any query to print in phpmyadmin

Comment: Not printing any query

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your view

Use this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="name">Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Enter name" value="<?php echo $r->first_name;?>" />
  </div>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="name">Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" nae="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Enter name" value="<?php echo $r->first_name;?>" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In your first name input field 'name' attribute has spell mistake.
Correct that 'nae' to 'name'

Comment: no it is not working corrected spell mistake as well